# Riffle an element with +1 every time

Tags: list-manipulation

I've been struggeling with the command riffle.

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, {13,14, 15}}
```

How do I use riffle like this, but add 1 to "X", every time it gets inserted?
So when it has inserted "X" 5 times, it would be X5, instead of just "X".

"X" is a string.

```
Riffle[list, "X", 3]

 {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, X, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, X, {13, 14, 15}}
```

The output I am looking for:

> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, X1, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, X2, {13, 14, 15}}

Comment: Why not spend some quality time with your previous riffle-related questions and learn from the comments/answers there? Once you get the hang of the basics, iterations on the insert-at-x-with-y become trivial.

Comment: @EminemIsLife, do you think you will ever start to accept the answers according to the site charter?

Comment: @EminemIsLife, I see I've managed it =)) You may just vote for all responses and add comments for those who might also deserved 'accept' check.

Comment: @EminemIsLife, by the way, if you want your comment got seeing by addressee, type `@<name>`. I repeat those thing because see that you like to quickly ask a lot of questions =))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a list to riffle with,

`Riffle[list, 
 Table[StringJoin["X", ToString[i]], {i, 1, Length[list]}], 3]`

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, "X1", {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, "X2", {13, 14, 
  15}}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
Module[{i = 1}, Riffle[list, "X", 3] /. "X" :> "X" <> ToString[i++]]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, "X1", {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, "X2", {13, 14,  15}}

Answer (score 7):

```
Riffle[list, Table["X" <> ToString[i], {i, Ceiling[Length[list]/3]}],
  3]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, "X1", {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, "X2", {13, 14, 15}}

Answer (score 1):

A variation of eldo's method that allows `"X"` to be present in the `list` itself without conflict.

```
incRiffle[L_List, s_String, p_: 2] :=
  Module[{i = 1},
    Riffle[L, Unevaluated@Symbol[s <> ToString[i++]], p]
  ]
```

Question example:

```
incRiffle[list, "X", 3]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, X1, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, X2, {13, 14, 15}}
> ```

Other examples:

```
incRiffle[Range@5, "a"]

incRiffle[{"W", "X", "Y", "Z"}, "X"]
```

> ```
> {1, a1, 2, a2, 3, a3, 4, a4, 5}
>
> {"W", X1, "X", X2, "Y", X3, "Z"}
> ```